# is it possible to use kernel function to calculate each instance of covariance matrix? If Yes why?

Tags: covariance, kernel-trick

I saw a paper that uses Gaussian kernel for calculation at covariance matrix of given variables. Is it mathematically Correct or not? if it is okay,what is the intuition behind ? What about using any distance function instead of Gaussian kernel?

Comment: Please tell us *how* a kernel was used to compute a covariance matrix.  Could you provide a link to the paper or at least a reference to it?  Please also explain the sense in which you conceive of a Gaussian kernel as a "distance function."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel values represent the **prior covariance**, not the covariance of the actual data points. Any symmetric positive definite matrix is a valid covariance matrix, and the reproducing kernel Hilbert space theory guarantees that there exist a Hilbert space where the mapped data will have exactly that covariance (Parzan's theory).

Choosing a good kernel is important as in any Bayesian inference. Any positive semi-definite defined on your data space can be used as a kernel, but many trivial or overly complex kernels do not capture the natural similarity or prior knowledge of the data well, and performs poorly. Gaussian (a.k.a. squared exponential) kernel is a good choice because it is known to be *universal*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is so enlighting. I have couple of more questions. What is that Hilber Space, can you explain a bit? And what prior covariance mean in layman term?

Comment: I recommend the GPML book for you. http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/